# Removing ], [ , spaces and commas in an arraylist and transposing it in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with an arraylist of strings in a txt file

```
[abc, def, ghi, jkl]
```

I need to remove all brackets, spaces and commas and then transposing it to get

```
adgjbehkcfil
```

I am using `JDK1.4.`(**sorry its JDK 1.6.0_24**)

Comment: Any Try?.........

Comment: what did you try so far? Is this part of your homework?

Comment: and JDK 1.4 ? come on.

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` came with 1.4, here's your solution

Comment: Seriously: when your only choice is Java 1.4; you should rather **only** study Java, and write down programs using a pen and a piece of paper. Meaning: first work on getting a newer Java in place ...

Comment: To be fair, at the office we are stuck with 1.6 because of some appliaction server used, and integration tools. But I can imagine a place were a server would still run 1.4.

Comment: Its java version 1.6....

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = "[abc, def, ghi, jkl]"
            .replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")
            .split(", ");
    char[] chars = new char[3 * strings.length];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < strings.length; idx++) {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < 3; pos++) {
            chars[idx + pos * strings.length] = strings[idx].charAt(pos);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(chars);
}
```

**Output**

```
adgjbehkcfil
```